# pandas.to_datetime inconsistent time string format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am attempting to convert the index of a `pandas.DataFrame` from string format to a datetime index, using `pandas.to_datetime()`.

Import pandas:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '0.10.1'
```

Create an example DataFrame:

```
In [3]: d = {'data' : pd.Series([1.,2.], index=['26/12/2012', '10/01/2013'])}

In [4]: df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Look at indices. Note that the date format is day/month/year:

```
In [5]: df.index
Out[5]: Index([26/12/2012, 10/01/2013], dtype=object)
```

Convert index to datetime:

```
In [6]: pd.to_datetime(df.index)
Out[6]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-12-26 00:00:00, 2013-10-01 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Already at this stage, you can see that the date format for each entry has been formatted differently. The first is fine, the second has swapped month and day.

This is what I want to write, but avoiding the inconsistent formatting of date strings:

```
In [7]: df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index))
Out[7]: 
data
2012-12-26   1
2013-10-01   2
```

I guess the first entry is correct because the function 'knows' there aren't 26 months, and so does not choose the default month/day/year format.

Is there another/better way to do this? Can I pass the format into the `to_datetime()` function?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I have found a way to do this, without pandas.to_datetime:

```
import datetime.datetime as dt
date_string_list = df.index.tolist()
datetime_list = [ dt.strptime(date_string_list[x], '%d/%m/%Y') for x in range(len(date_string_list)) ]
df.index=datetime_list
```

but it's a bit messy. Any improvements welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are (hidden?) `dayfirst` argument to [`to_datetime`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/tools.py#L51):

```
In [23]: pd.to_datetime(df.index, dayfirst=True)
Out[23]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-12-26 00:00:00, 2013-01-10 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

In pandas 0.11 (onwards) you'll be able to use the `format` argument:

```
In [24]: pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%Y')
Out[24]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-12-26 00:00:00, 2013-01-10 00:00:00]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Thanks @andy. The `dayfirst` arg works. But I cannot use `format`. `TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`. Should that be available in the pandas version I'm using (0.10.1)?

Comment: @random.me ah Sorry. It won't be, I was working in dev (so it'll be 0.11)!

Comment: Thank you this has been helpful. I am working on version 0.15 and pandas still gets confused if I don't feed in the `dayfirst=True` parameter so introducing `format` clearly hasn't helped.

Comment: @Zhubarb it's **very** "forgiving" which is almost never what you want. Worse it's not consistent within a column, so without dayfirst it looks up US-style dates first then UK-style, so if you're all UK-style it'll translate before the 12th: day-mon-year as mon-day-year, and 13th onwards correctly. The annoying part is that IIRC this uses some very old python date lib which is very difficult to touch/fix. :(