# Specifying date format when converting with pandas.to_datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have data in a csv file with dates stored as strings in a standard UK format - `%d/%m/%Y` - meaning they look like:

```
12/01/2012
30/01/2012
```

The examples above represent 12 January 2012 and 30 January 2012.

When I import this data with pandas version 0.11.0 I applied the following transformation:

```
import pandas as pd
...
cpts.Date = cpts.Date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

but it converted dates inconsistently. To use my existing example, 12/01/2012 would convert as a datetime object representing 1 December 2012 but 30/01/2012 converts as 30 January 2012, which is what I want.

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929861/pandas-to-datetime-inconsistent-time-string-format) I tried:

```
cpts.Date = cpts.Date.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

but the results are exactly the same. The [source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.11.0/pandas/tseries/tools.py) suggests I'm doing things right so I'm at a loss. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use `read_csv`? Because then you can do it directly while reading in.

Comment: @joris Yes I did use `read_csv`. Could you tell what function does the date conversion, and does it handle my formatting issues?

Comment: But coming back to your original question (because this should also work), what version did you use, because for me it works.

Comment: @joris seems to be the case in 11.0 and dev, posted as [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3669)

Comment: @AndyHayden but apparantly only for series, I tried it on a (one-column) dataframe which worked

Comment: @joris sorry for going missing for a while. Am I understanding correctly to say that a single column of a pd.DataFrame, which is what I'm passing, is a pd.Series? And that is therefore why my call currently isn't working?

Comment: Yes, accessing a single column will return a Series. So you could try `cpts[['Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime, ...)` as a workaround (due to the double [ it will return a dataframe with one column). But note that it should also work on a Series (it is a bug it doesn't), and that the easier way is just to call `pd.to_datetime(..)` on the column directly as @AndyHayden pointed out in his answer or to do the conversion in `read_csv`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `parse_dates` option from `read_csv` to do the conversion directly while reading you data.
The trick here is to use `dayfirst=True` to indicate your dates start with the day and not with the month. See here for more information: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

When your dates have to be the index:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = StringIO("""date,value
... 12/01/2012,1
... 12/01/2012,2
... 30/01/2012,3""")
>>> 
>>> pd.read_csv(s, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
            value
date             
2012-01-12      1
2012-01-12      2
2012-01-30      3
```

Or when your dates are just in a certain column:

```
>>> s = StringIO("""date
... 12/01/2012
... 12/01/2012
... 30/01/2012""")
>>> 
>>> pd.read_csv(s, parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True)
                 date
0 2012-01-12 00:00:00
1 2012-01-12 00:00:00
2 2012-01-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: You can also set a custom parser, this works ok for me: `df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", parse_dates=['date_column'], date_parser=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, format="%Y/%m/%d", errors="coerce"))`

Answer (score 18):

*I think you are calling it correctly, and I posted this as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3669).*

You can just specify the format to `to_datetime` directly, for example:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(['12/1/2012', '30/01/2012'])

In [2]: pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d/%m/%Y')
Out[2]:
0   2012-01-12 00:00:00
1   2012-01-30 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Update: As OP correctly points out this doesn't work with NaN, if you are happy with `dayfirst=True` (which works with NaN too):

```
s.apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)
```

*Worth noting that have to be careful using `dayfirst` (which is easier than specifying the exact format), since [`dayfirst` isn't strict](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3341).*

Comment: thanks this solution is appealing, but it doesn't currently work with missing data, which I have. I suspect the `coerce` argument for `pd.to_datetime` in dev would fix that but I can't upgrade my work environment until it's a stable release.

Comment: @cms_mgr What about: `s.apply(lambda t: pd.to_datetime(t, format='%d/%m/%Y'))`, works with NaN.

Comment: That still fiddles with the dates I'm afraid. Looks like it's a bug - think it might be the first I've ever found!

Comment: If only someone had standardised an international date format. Oh, [wait](http://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: @cms_mgr actually I remember testing that earlier (and it not working). I think that may *also* be a bug...

Comment: @cms_mgr ha, compare `pd.to_datetime(s[0], format='%d/%m/%Y', dayfirst=True)` and `pd.to_datetime(s[0], format='%d/%m/%Y')`, definitely a bug, perhaps the entire bug.

Comment: @cms_mgr I think dayfirst is the solution for the moment, see update (works with NaN).

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've upvoted this but accepted joris's answer as he proposed it first.