# pandas transform to a boolean column matching its maximum

Tags: python, pandas

while helping in this post [Generating new time series index from existing data set in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809125/generating-new-time-series-index-from-existing-data-set-in-pandas/24809538?noredirect=1#comment38514026_24809538)
, I got a question myself, for a dataframe like this :

```
In [44]: newdf
Out[44]: 
           date
id             
3001 2000-01-01
3001 2000-01-02
3001 2000-01-03
3001 2000-01-04
3001 2000-01-05
3849 2001-01-05
3849 2001-01-06
3849 2001-01-07
3849 2001-01-08
8927 2006-01-06
8927 2006-01-07
8927 2006-01-08
8927 2006-01-09
```

how to add a third column, which is zero for all the rows but the last date for each id? for each end_data it is equal to one?

I edited my answer that does this:

```
In [32]: b = newdf.reset_index().groupby( 'id').date.transform( 
lambda ii : ii.max())
In [37]: newdf['new_col'] = (newdf.date == b).astype(int)
```

but I don't know why cann't I just do:

```
newdf['new_col'] = newdf.reset_index().groupby( 'id').date.transform( lambda ii : ii == ii.max())
```

which gives me error:

```
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with a slight modification:

```
newdf['new_col'] = [v for v in newdf.reset_index().groupby( 'id').date.transform( lambda ii : ii == ii.max())]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
df2 = newdf.reset_index()
df2['new_col'] = df2.groupby( 'id').date.transform( lambda ii : ii == ii.max())
```

The result of your `....groupby( 'id').date.transform( lambda ii : ii == ii.max())` is a Series, but the index of that series is range(len(df)). When you try to do `newdf['new_col'] = new series`, it tries to match the indices. Casting to list makes pandas ignore the indices, or reseting the index first puts the indices on the same level.

As a side note, for speed, it looks like your data is sorted by ('id','date'), which is a nice property to use (groupby gets really slow for large dfs):

```
# guarantee sorting
newdf.reset_index(inplace=True).sort(('id','date'), inplace=True).set_index('id')
# init new column
newdf['is_last'] = 0
curr_id = None
for i, (id, row) in enumerate(newdf.iterrows()):
    if i > 0 and id != curr_id:
        newdf.iloc[i-1]['is_last'] = 1
```

Comment: wait, so groupby("KEY").agg(...) makes "KEY" the index, while groupby("KEY").transform(...) produces index [0,1,2,3....] ?