# Date format incorrect from CSV in Excel to Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, date

When I open a CSV file in Excel to examine the data, the date comes up as `"21-Jun"`. When I click the cell, I can see in the formula bar it is `"06/21/2018"`. 
When I read the csv file into a pandas dataframe, the date comes up as `"21-Jun"`.

During the reading of the csv, how can I specify to put it in proper date format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying date format when converting with pandas.to\_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672237/specifying-date-format-when-converting-with-pandas-to-datetime)

Comment: Check the column type. Is it datetime? then it is only appearances - the datetime is correctly used as datetime. whatfor do you need a special format? Displaying? Storing as csv again? Computing dateranges? Please provide code that displays the problem you have and some expected output so we can help you out. There are plenty of OP about pandas and csv - good chance your question is already covered in one. Did you search on SO? What did you find? Why did it not help you?