# How to read datetime in Pandas with read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dateset with a date column called "zeitpunkt". The time is recorded in utc+1. I have other similar files where I just use parse_dates=["name of column"] in pd.read_csv and it works fine. But with this csv I can't get the datetime column recognized as a datetime column, it still is an object. Any ideas why I am not able to convert it to datetime?

My goal is to access specific days like the mean of monday or the mean of march.

The head of the column looks like this:

```
0 2019-01-01 00:30:00+01
1 2019-01-01 00:35:00+01
2 2019-01-01 00:40:00+01
3 2019-01-01 00:45:00+01
4 2019-01-01 00:50:00+01
```

dtypes still shows me object after I use either parse_dates=True or parse_dates=["zeitpunkt"]

Comment: instead of specifying `parse_dates`, after you loaded the csv to a df, you can also run `df["zeitpunkt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["zeitpunkt"])`.

Comment: It seems that your problem is that you lack the header line? You can force read_csv to use headers from a list (check the read_csv documentation)

Comment: read it as a string and checkout datetime.strptime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specifying date format when converting with pandas.to\_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672237/specifying-date-format-when-converting-with-pandas-to-datetime)

Comment: @sushanth don't think so; pd.to_datetime parses the format without specifying it explicitly. It might be a good idea to set `utc=True` though and continue working with UTC instead of the fixed offset.

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks, utc=True works fine.

Comment: @Gobrel ok so I kind of misinterpreted your question in my first comment ;-) object dtype actually results from mixed UTC offsets, pandas can't handle that with the built-in datetime64[ns] dtype. Conversion to UTC normalizes all the offsets. If you need datetime in a certain time zone, use `.dt.tz_convert("name-of-time-zone")` after having datetime in UTC.